# How to set Y axis custom label using MigraDoc?

Tags: c#, charts, migradoc

I am trying to draw graph using `MigraDoc.DocumentObjectModel.Shapes.Charts`.
I want to avoid to get y axis label generated automatically.
Do you anybody how to set custom Y axis label using MigraDoc?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I only know how to set Y axis label formatted as percents:

`chart.YAxis.TickLabels.Format = "#0%";`

I don't know if there is some other ways of changing Y axis label neither if there is other `TickLabels.Format` formats since I can't find any documentation on the topic.

EDIT: I'm not sure about it, but it looks like the format used for `TickLabels.Format` follows the rules described here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx .
Again, this is only helpful if you only want to change the format of Y axis label.

Answer (score 0):

I did it like this:

```
Chart plotter = new Chart();

// add your series and datapoints here...

// Format Y - Axis 
plotter.YAxis.MinimumScale = -100;
plotter.YAxis.MaximumScale = 100;
plotter.YAxis.MajorTick = 50;
plotter.YAxis.MajorTickMark = TickMarkType.Outside;
```

The result looks like this:

[image]